# Selenium Caution: '/usr/bin/google-chrome': file is a script file, not a real executable. The browser environment is no longer fully under RC control

Tags: java, grails, selenium, ubuntu-12.04, functional-testing

I am getting the above error when I run a functional test-case in a Grails project using Selenium 2.0.RC1 plugin on Ubuntu 12.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens when you have this in your SeleniumConfig.groovy file:

> browser = "*googlechrome /usr/bin/chromium-browser"

You should actually be referencing the binary distribution file:

> browser = "*googlechrome /opt/google/chrome/chrome"

But you can only do this if you have google-chrome installed in Ubuntu and NOT chromium-browser (some Linux distributions package up Chromium for easy installation - see here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome)

To determine what you have, open a command and type:

> whereis google-chrome

If you get a blank back (or just the words google-chrome) then you know you don't have google-chrome. Next type:

> whereis chromium-browser.

If this returns something like  /usr/bin/chromium-browser then you know you have chromium-browser and you need to update to google-chrome to fix this error (https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?platform=linux)

Once you've installed google-chrome, replace the browser line in SeleniumConfig.groovy with this:

> browser = "*googlechrome /opt/google/chrome/chrome"